# JDBC giving me Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, jdbc

Getting `Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)` error on the line that is marked below.  Any ideas?

```
            ...
            int hash = ConsistantHash.hash(name);
            query = "INSERT INTO `server_info` (`host`, `port, `s_port`, `name`, `hash`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            statement.setString(1, host); //this line
            statement.setInt(2, c_port);
            statement.setInt(3, s_port);
            statement.setString(4, name);
            statement.setInt(5, hash);

            statement.executeUpdate();
            statement.close();
```

Comment: are you by any chance reusing the same `statement` variable elsewhere / in other threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a matching escape of the port column:

```
`port
```

Should be

```
`port`
```

Comment: THAT WAS SO HARD TO CATCH.  I spent like 20 minutes on this. LOL

Comment: @jonah, I passed it up at first as well.  But then I decide there must be something that is blocking the parameters from being seen as parameters and I started to double check the `'s